# Are mobile apps dropping UX in favor of super-clean interfaces? If so, why?

Tags: mobile-application, interface

Today's mobile apps, compared to 5-6 years ago are way cleaner visually.

Nowadays you can find several popular apps with a way that is really so clean that there is no value proposition on the login screen, not even a single picture apart from the logo: check [Twitch](https://mobbin.design/apps/twitch) currently or Instagram login screens compared (attached).

I saw so many times apps with forms where the input rules were not visible, and you would only see the error after filling up everything and pressing the "proceed" button to go back and see the issue to correct.

Did I freeze on time? Why are apps dropping so much potential in UX for a super-clean interface?

[image: Instagram 2014]
[image: Instagram 2020]

Comment: Why do you assume that a clean look isn't optimized UX?

Comment: Good question. From @fansuriarrumi 's comment the two main actions here are pretty clear, which is optimal. From a new user's perspective, though, I have no idea what this app can help me with

Comment: It means - should communication about the app be totally trusted to content from the website and the App Store? Should I trust that my app's value prop and overall functioning is understood by the users already?

Answer (score 1):

Talking about the current Instagram UI, I think as a user I have a more clear pathway to seeing which objective should I take (Create new account / Login). Compare to the old UI, I have to consider 3 types of buttons at the first sight.

Answer (score 0):

I don't entirely disagree with you on this. However, cleaner UIs do tend to have a positive impact on UX(but not always). I suspect this is more of a trend where design leaders like Apple are setting the minimalistic trend.